Is it possible to use XGBost with unstructured data?
I have several 2D experimental curves without a regular space and number of points, these curves are function of 2 (or more parameters). Is it possible to use XGBoost to predict curves for a set of parameters. It work fine if the experimental curves have the same number of points and a regular space between the point. One possibility is to interpolate the data in order to generate a new 'rugular' data set but this approach can introduce some errors.
I expect to have the method to use XGBost with this type of dataset
One code possible :
x=[[6 520 4],
[6 530 2],
[6 520 1],
[6 510 1],
[4 520 1]]

y = [[[0.2 100],
[0.3 120],
[0.4 140],
[0.5 160],
[0.6 170],
[0.7 180],
[0.8 190],
],
[[0.22 100],
[0.31 320],
[0.4 440],
[0.53 560],
[0.6 370],
[0.7 880],
],
[[0.21 100],
[0.3 140],
[0.42 190],
[0.52 200,
],
[[0.2 100],
[0.3 120],
[0.34 140],
[0.5 160],
[0.67 170],
[0.7 180],
[0.8 200],
],
[[0.2 100],
[0.32 105],
[0.4 140],
[0.5 160],
[0.61 220],
]]

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x, y, 
test_size=0.2, random_state=7)

model_xgboost = xgboost.XGBRegressor(booster='gbtree', 
objective='reg:squarederror',
                                 n_estimators=10000, 
max_depth=a_max_depth, eta=a_eta,           subsample=1,
                                 colsample_bytree=1,
                                 
min_child_weight=a_min_child_weight,
                                 max_bin=100,
                                 tree_method="hist",
                                 reg_alpha=0.1,
                                 gamma=10,
                                 refresh_leaf=0)
                             
model_xgboost.fit(x_train, y_train)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
